# Python SSL Error- Error while sending email using Mandrill / Djrill

Tags: python, django, ssl, openssl, mandrill

I get the below error while sending mail using djrill.

```
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
app_1 | response = wrapped_callback(request, callback_args, *callback_kwargs)
app_1 | File "/code/invitations/views.py", line 102, in request_invite
app_1 | msg.send()
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
app_1 | return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djrill/mail/backends/djrill.py", line 81, in send_messages
app_1 | sent = self._send(message)
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djrill/mail/backends/djrill.py", line 132, in _send
app_1 | response = requests.post(api_url, data=api_data)
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
app_1 | return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, *kwargs)
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
app_1 | response = session.request(method=method, url=url, *kwargs)
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
app_1 | resp = self.send(prep, *send_kwargs)
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
app_1 | r = adapter.send(request, *kwargs)
app_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
app_1 | raise SSLError(e, request=request)
app_1 | SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

I suspect this is an issue with python, openssl and not with Djrill. This application runs fine on another server so I am at my wits end.

I would appreciate any help in sorting this issue out

Thanks!

Comment: This is an indication that the ssl server your python program is connecting to does not have a valid SSL certificate. 'not valid' means that it might be a self-signed certificate, or the certificate might have expired, or perhaps that the certificate if not for the host server that is offering it. There was a somewhat intrusive change in python 2.7.9 and 3.something to make this an exception (I think it used to be a warning). Personally as I write scripts for intranet use where we *never* have full ssl certificates I have stuck to 2.7.8, disabled the warning message, and am happy. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else running into this issue, please refer to the below link:

https://github.com/brack3t/Djrill/issues/101

Thanks again to donspaulding